# Trying to have parent component pass one var from child component to another child component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have 2 child components inside of a parent component. I then have child component 1, fire a custom event that is then caught by the parent component. But how am I then able to get that custom event to reach child component 2? I am just trying to grab an updated variable of boolean value without using pub/sub or messageChannels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent would just update an attribute and/or call a method on child2. Events always propagate upwards, not downwards, so in order to notify child2 without pubsub/messaging, this is the correct model.

```
// parent calling an @api labeled method
handleUpdateFromChild1(event) {
  this.template.querySelector('c-child2').notify(event);
}
```

Or:

```
// Parent setting a bound attribute value
handleUpdateFromChild1(event) {
  this.someCheckbox = event.detail.value;
}
```

Or:

```
// Parent passing in an @api bound property
handleUpdateFromChild1(event) {
  this.template.querySelector('c-child2').someValue = event.detail.value;
}
```

The child can then act appropriately:

```
// As a getter/setter pair
_someValue = false;
@api get someValue {
  return this._someValue;
}
set someValue(value) {
  this._someValue = value;
  // You can do more stuff here
}
```

Or:

```
@api notify(event) {
  this._someValue = event.detail.value;
}
```

Etc.

There's a lot of ways to do this if you are willing to have the parent notify the child. You just can't have this wired automatically between the two children without getting the parent involved, unless you want to use pubsub/messaging.

Comment: ah okay, thank you. I will try these to see what works best. I originally tried using @api to update the var on child2 when it would change on child1 when it would dispatch to the parent with an event.